# Flex: tabbar used with viewstack => problem with element removal

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

When I remove an element from a viewstack then the body is removed but the tabbar header is still displayed

I would like them both to be displayed.

Comment: Show your code.  Nothing ties a ViewStack to a Tabbar .

Answer (score 0):

If you use the viewstack as dataProvider for the tabbar, the tabs will be updated when the viewstack has children added/removed. Otherwise you'll have to update the tabs yourself by removing the corresponding element in the dataprovider of the TabBar.

Comment: i mean to say that if i change visible and includeInLayout property of viewstack child then it is not apply on tabbarchild.Why?

Comment: The TabBar registers events for collection change or child add/remove in case of the viewStack. Setting the visible and includeInLayout to false doesn't physically remove the child from the viewstack, so the tab bar doesn't react to that change. You'd be better off using removeChild/addChild in this case.